# Function count data result separated into commas

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT count(clics)
FROM clicscount
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

The result is the sum of the clicks made in the last week.

Example source data:

```
Thursday:  5 clics
Friday:    5 clics
Saturday:  5 clics
Sunday:    5 clics
Monday:    5 clics
Tuesday:   5 clics
Wednesday: 5 clics
Today:     5 clics
```

The result displayed is `40` because the function shows the sum of all clicks.

However I want to show the data in an array of clicks per day such as:

```
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
```

Comment: Then, you can't use sum, remove the count from the SQL query and get results. Then loop results to generate the response that you want.

Comment: @CoryCharlton you don't need to add a comment when you edit- there is a field on the edit section for that.

Comment: @Popnoodles pretty sure I did use the field in the edit. Or at least that's what I intended to do :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp.c SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (
  SELECT count(clics) c
  FROM clicscount
  WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
  GROUP BY date
) as tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
while($i < 8){
$result[$i]=SELECT count(clics) FROM clicscount WHERE date = CURDATE()-$i;
$i++;
}
```

$result is the required array.